# VW Golf fuel filler cap will not unlock

Tags: vw, golf, fuel-cap

The fuel filler flap on my 09 VW Golf estate (diesel) will not unlock. I have tried locking and unlocking the car which should relase the filler flap but it remains locked. The owner's manual says there is no method of manual relase on this model. Can anyone suggest how I can get it open?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked for a blown fuse? You may also be able to reach the release either by reaching into the wheel well or removing an interior panel. Another option is that the latch is released but the spring that pops the door open is broken. Have an assistant try to open the door while you actuate the switch.

Comment: Agree'd. I would check for a blown fuse / bad relay. I had a similar issue on my 01 VW Beetle. My fuel door switch failed and I couldn't open my fuel door.

Answer (score 3):

Locking and unlocking the car while applying a little pressure on the flap worked for me .  Repeat if it doesn't work the first time.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved things for us. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Get in the car and lock all doors using the switch on the drivers door. Then unlock all doors using switch on the key. I found that this worked and the flap would then open when pushed as normal.

Comment: Kindly explain what kind of voodoo is this? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my 2013 Passat wagon.  I took the car to the dealer and the mechanic repeatedly pressed the unlock on the remote while at the same time pressing and releasing the fuel flap.  It worked.  He explained that the flap lock can fail in a number of ways.  In my case it just got stuck and the press-release was sufficient to solve the problem.  In other cases the lock can actually break in which case you just have to take it to the dealer to get replaced.  I'm getting it replaced at the next service.

Answer (score 1):

For any one who has found this thread and is still stuck, I solved this by:

Getting a tyre lever inside the fuel cap and gently forcing it open a bit whilst repeatedly pressing unlock on the key fob.

Once its open you can look into preventing it from happening again. I ended up taking the whole fuel cap section out and duct taping a bit of metal in the way of the lock to physically prevent it from being locked again.

This obviously means the fuel cap will never lock so bit of security risk but its a great solution in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have had a relay get reversed on them, that is, they locked their Golf only to find that the fuel flap was unlocked. Give this a try, and also try locking and unlocking your golf several times to attempt to reset things.

Answer (score 0):

With filler flap in the open position, lock doors using key. You will now be able to open and close the filler flap freely. Thereafter you must remember to release the flap before locking the doors. The only downside is that although the flap is closed, it will not be locked.

Comment: Welcome to the site, David. Good to see you jumping in to help answer questions. Just an FYI, this question is more than 5 years old. Chances are good you will not get a response from the OP.

Comment: @CharlieRB - It's all good. Remember, the information which is presented here is not only for the original user, but for anyone else who may come looking. If David has information which adds to or actually answers the question, so much the better. Don't be afraid to do it yourself! :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Yep, I know. No problem with new answers to old questions, I was just letting the new user know they might not get a response due to age. Trying to be helpful and encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing unlock more than once did it for me, nothing else worked, almost tried prying the whole cap off!